# How to send lots of (x,y) coordinates over the network?

Tags: android, ruby, google-app-engine, networking, heroku

I'm making an Android app that requires a line graph so I need the (x,y) coordinates from the server.

We're building the back-end using Ruby on Rails with Heroku (though we're also considering Google AppEngine).

What's the best way to send hundreds of (x,y) coordinates over the network (encoded in JSON?) to an Android device?

Comment: If it's one line you only need _two_ (x,y) coords, right?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Comment: It's a line-graph so there can be hundreds of points. Like this http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/graphs/images/line_example1.jpg

Comment: "encoded in JSON?" yes why not? JSON is quite space efficient to transfer and has good parsing / generation support. The most efficient way is to create a binary stream (alternating x, y). That's also simple to "parse"

Comment: I think the best way is JSON or XML without space, tabulation... to have a smaller size. But Brian Roach is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're massively concerned about bandwidth, pack the coordinates into a binary format.  For example, assuming a 2-d grid of (x,y) coordinates as 32 bit integers.  Using ruby:

```
points = [[107897,598654], [876432,30001], [15,754689]]
# => [[107897, 598654], [876432, 30001], [15, 754689]]

# json size
points.to_json.length
# => 44

# make a byte stream of points
data = points.flatten.pack("V*")
# => "y\xA5\x01\x00~\"\t\x00\x90_\r\x001u\x00\x00\x0F\x00\x00\x00\x01\x84\v\x00"

# binary size
data.length
# => 24

# read a byte stream to points
points = data.unpack("V*").each_slice(2).to_a
# => [[107897, 598654], [876432, 30001], [15, 754689]]
```

Comment: If your integers will always fit inside 16 bits, use a smaller pack format too.  Obviously each 32 bit integer will consume 4 bytes of space, even in its under 1000, which in ascii consumes less space.

Comment: Note that you can also introspect the values before encoding, to select a suitable pack format. The issue is then knowing how to unpack the bytes. A rudimentary approach would be add a 1-byte header to the stream, which would represent an enum, say 0=8 bits, 1=16 bits, 2=24 bits, 3=32 bits. Once you have that byte read, unpack the remaining string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're generating line charts, you might want to take inspiration from the Google Chart service's simple and extended [text encodings](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#simple). The main takeaway is that you don't need to transmit the actual values; just their relative values and the limits.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to encode it with `JSON` or `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no ruby experience, but you could just send the coordinates in order, separated by newlines, in XML (maybe something along the lines of:`<coordinate use='errorbar'>1,2</coordinate>` for each coordinate [in your ruby script]), separated by newlines, and download the result in android using:

```
public static String[] download(String web_url) throws IOException{
    URL website = new URL(web_url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(
              website.openStream()));
    String input;
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        stringList.add(input);
    }
    String[] itemArray = new String[stringList.size()];
    String[] returnedArray = stringList.toArray(itemArray);
    return returnedArray;
}
// Of course, call this function with web_url as the URL to your script
```

That will get you the XML output, each line as an entry in the array, and then you just have to parse the XML. If you are certain you will never need extra data, you could just send it in plain text, with no need to parse XML.